# How to specify version number when using Jenkins and Generic-Artifactory Integration?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am able to integrate jenkins with artifactory to store my artifacts whenever a build is carried out, however whenever new artifacts are being pushed, the older versions will be removed automatically.

So I will like to check is there anyway for me to label each artifacts according to the version number or build number for easy version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to include the Jenkins `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` in the artifact path and name.

Assuming your Artifactory repository is set up as a Maven repository your pipeline should include something like this:

```
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "${env.PACKAGING_FOLDER}/${env.REPOSITORY_APPLICATION}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.zip",
            "target": "${env.REPOSITORY_CODE}/${env.REPOSITORY_GROUP}/${env.REPOSITORY_APPLICATION}/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${env.REPOSITORY_APPLICATION}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.zip",
            "regexp": "true"
        }
    ]
}"""

def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo.env.capture = true

buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)
server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is working fine! But I see that under the Build Info JSON, there is a predefined "version": "1.0.1".

I also like to check how do I actually access and configure the version number?

Comment: Updated my answer with details on how to deal with the build info.  The ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} is the Jenkins Build number and increments every build.

Comment: Would appreciate if you could accept and upvote if this answer help you.  Thank you.